# Playing mp3 files placed outside root folder using jplayer

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess, jplayer

i have searched all around the web to find a solution for this and i found some of them which involves php based solutions like chunking or other ones which involves mod_xsendfile() etc. but i couldn't find solution to the exact problem.

Here is the issue :

I am using jplayer to play music on my website. what i want is when a user adds a song to the playlist it gets added to jplayer list (which i have already tested, no issues in that, i am doing it by passing JSON object to java script to add that song to playlist(which also involves passing of complete url of song)) but i don't want the user to see the exact url of the mp3. or even if he is able to see it, he shouldn't be able to access it by directly typing that url in the browser, however i am fine with downloading.

I am using hostgator as webhost which provides me the access to place my files outside root folder, which might be a restriction on other hosts like godaddy, but it still not supports mod_xsendfile() on shared hosting, so please avoid answers related to that.

I am fine with any of the solutions whether i need to keep my files outside root or inside it, but i just want to protect direct access to files.

Answer (score 1):

Jplayer needs a URL that returns the raw MP3 data. Therefore, it either needs to be able to read the file directly, or some other way to have it sent out to it.

The classic solution here (without a system like X-SendFile) is a PHP script that checks the relevant permissions and then send the required file. If someone doesn't have permission, it could send a different file to tell them, or other way to inform the user.

Perform your validation checks, and then, if it's OK, call http://php.net/readfile with the path to the file. It will send the file from disk. You'll probably also need to set some headers for the mime-type first, as well.

Comment: but this solution seems to have some problems as most of the hosts have default timeout set for php scripts, so there are chances that script may be forcefully killed by the host before the file transfer completes.